# How to calculate the available anchorage length in reinforce concrete design?

Tags: concrete, reinforced-concrete

Hello everyone I am taking a course on RC this semester and I am kinda bumped out by all of the terminology here.

**The main question I have is what is the difference between anchorage length and development length and how to calculate the available anchorage length**

I am doing the following question:

[image]

Can someone please help me understand parts of the solution? Here my lecturer is checking if the 3N24 are fully anchored.

[image]

538 is the effective shear depth, 225 is width of the support, 900 is the development length, 30 is the cover. Can someone please explain the above calculations and perhaps show me a diagram?

Here is a diagram of the situation:

[image]

Comment: So you should be asking your lecturer, they gave the lecture, question and solution..

Comment: Many countries have developed their own RC design code, I guess you are using AU or NZ code.